# How to update information from an array to firebase?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My goal is to update a specific document by adding +1 everytime is "buyed", This is how the data enters I can either use this:

`const data = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("listaLibros"))`

which comes like this in the console log:

[image]

or I can transform all that data into a single array (idk which way would be easier to achieve what I want to do which is why I mention both)

`const allItems = [...data1, ...data2, ...data3]`

and then it comes like this:

[image]

However the reason why I had them "separated" as 4,0,3 is because each array is from a DIFFERENT collection and this time I had none from the second collection which is why it brings 0.

Now the idea is that for every BOOK it adds a +1 as "ordered" in their respective collection each book has his own uid which in this case is added on the document as id one of the examples in the picture is PE-13620 for example.

how can I compare my array information which the collections I think the best approach would be using the one with the separate arrays that way I can divide it by collection

```
    let data1 = data[0] //Collection A
    let data2 = data[1] //Collection B
    let data3 = data[2] //Collection C
```

I know you can use .where('id', 'array-contains', data[0].id) I think ?
but how do I use this for updating each one matched ? and to add the +1 would it be as simple as doing something like this ?

```
.update({
ordered: ++1 
})
```

**Update 1** Image showing how the user select each piece of data from each collection before "paying"

[image]

Collection B is not always empty, but for this example it is.

**Update 2**

So when you are in the "pay" screen the 3 arrays from before merge into 1  (as I mention before... const allItems = [...data1, ...data2, ...data3])

[image]

and when the person is gonna press Pay I would need to know how to use the arrays data1, data2 and data3 to check into each book and update the collection and add a +1 in "ordered". So far I do a new document to store all this into an order but I haven't figure out how to update that the book has +1 in "ordered"

so for the order I do the following:

```
const docRef = db.collection('usuarios').doc(user.uid).collection('pedidos').doc(docId)
        docRef.get().then((doc) => {
                docRef.set({
                    acudiente: user.displayName,
                    email: user.email,
                    phone: phone,
                    nombre: nombre,
                    grado: grado,
                    total: totalPrice,
                    totalPagado: 0,
                    escuela: escuela,
                    metodoDePago: "ACH",
                    banco: "Global Bank",
                    estadoDePago: "Pendiente",
                    fecha: formattedDate,
                    id: docId,
                    data: allItems
            }).then((r) => {
                history.push("/Inicio");
            })
    })

//I was thinking here add a query or something (for each one)  but didn't
//work it brings data1.id as undentified
const librosRefNuevos = db.collection('libros');
const queryRefNuevos = librosRefNuevos.where('id', 'array-contains', data1.id);
```

However if I do data1[0].id it does bring back the first id of the array so maybe a for each but idk how to do a for each with where... maybe I'm complicating myself that's why I'm here lol

I hope this was more descriptive let me know if require anything else

This is how it looks in the firebase

[image]

**FIXED**

```
 const ref1 = db.collection('libros');
    const increment = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);
    for (let i = 0; i < data1.length; i++){

    ref1.doc(data1[i].id).update({
      ordenado: increment
    })
  }

  const ref2 = db.collection('libros_Opcionales');
    for (let i = 0; i < data2.length; i++){

    ref2.doc(data2[i].id).update({
      ordenado: increment
    })
  }

  const ref3 = db.collection('productos_AIB');
    for (let i = 0; i < data3.length; i++){

    ref3.doc(data3[i].id).update({
      ordenado: increment
    })
  }
```

Comment: I highly recommend switching from a `Book[][]` to a `Record<string, Book[]>` where the string is the collection path or just the name. e.g. `listaLibros = { "collectionA": booksInA, "collectionB": booksInB, "collectionC": booksInC }`. Then if a particular collection is empty, you can simply omit it.

Comment: I think that piece of code got misunderstood data[0,1,2 etc] defines the collection 0 is the first one , 1 is the second collection , 2 is the third and last collection each bit has all the books from THAT collection which is why is showed as 4,0,3 in the array print

Comment: While I understand what you are trying to do I'll make myself clearer - if your code can be misunderstood, it's bad code. What if you needed to add a new collection? What if the order of the collection doesn't make sense? What if you needed to add a collection between A and B? What if a new person came along destructure your array into `const [colA, colC] = data` and obviously missed `colB` so now all the data is messed up? What if I only needed the data from C, how do I know that C is in index 2? How do I know which index is what 100 lines further down in the code?

Comment: Welp I said data is divided in 3 arrays each array represents a collection which I did mention. The way I divided is with data[0] as the first collection,  data[1]  as the second collection and lastly data[2] as the last collection.

Comment: Also I do not need new collections and the user can't add more than 3 because is getting the data from a table where you can select the books from each collection, I can upload a picture if you require it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the other answer I manage to make an answer as well that works for me

```
const ref1 = db.collection('libros');
    const increment = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);
    for (let i = 0; i < data1.length; i++){

    ref1.doc(data1[i].id).update({
      ordenado: increment
    })
  }

  const ref2 = db.collection('libros_Opcionales');
    for (let i = 0; i < data2.length; i++){

    ref2.doc(data2[i].id).update({
      ordenado: increment
    })
  }

  const ref3 = db.collection('productos_AIB');
    for (let i = 0; i < data3.length; i++){

    ref3.doc(data3[i].id).update({
      ordenado: increment
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply iterate through each `data` array and check for the existence of a corresponding document in each collection before updating the field.

```
const data = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("listaLibros"));

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (const item of data[i]) {
        // Check libros
        const libro = await db.doc(`libros/{item.id}`).get();
        if (libro.exists) {
            await db.doc(`libros/{item.id}`).update({
                ordered: libro.get('ordered') + 1
            })
        }
        
        // Check libros_Opcionales
        const libroOpcional = await db.doc(`libros_Opcionales/{item.id}`).get();
        if (libroOpcional.exists) {
            await db.doc(`libros_Opcionales/{item.id}`).update({
                ordered: libroOpcional.get('ordered') + 1
            })
        }

        // Check productos_AIB
        const producto = await db.doc(`productos_AIB/{item.id}`).get();
        if (producto.exists) {
            await db.doc(`productos_AIB/{item.id}`).update({
                ordered: producto.get('ordered') + 1
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but wont the int 1=0; i < 3 would only do 3 documents ? the amount of documents in data1, data2 and data3 are always changing

Comment: Following this I think I would i < data1.lenght also for the db would be db.collection('libros').doc(data1[i].id) let me give it a few tries and i'll let you know

Comment: @ReactPotato My understanding was that `data` was made up of three arrays, each one of varying length. The second loop iterates through all the values, regardless of length. `data` only has three members, no?

Comment: yeah is only data1, data2 and data3 however I do not understand why you have `for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)` wouldn't that just only check data 3 times ? Also I believe that you have to separate the for loops since they have different lengths. I'm gonna update what I just did based on what I saw from your code (Which is working) but the +1 seems to be overwriting instead of ++1

Comment: Also libro.get('ordered') doesn't work it just tells me is not defined so instead I decided to check for the value